# How to provide a default value for a function argument in ATS?

Tags: ats

Say I have a function declared as follows:

```
fun foo(x: int, y: bool): string
```

I would like to write `foo(x)` to mean `foo(x, false)`. Is there a way to
support this in ATS?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do as follows:

```
fun foo_full (x:int, y:bool): string = ... // your function, renamed
fun foo_def (x:int): string = foo_full (x, false)
overload foo with foo_full
overload foo with foo_def
```

This feature is called symbol overloading. `foo` is a symbol (introduced implicitly by the first `overload` declaration), and it can stand for two different functions.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use templates. For instance,

```
fun{} foo$y(): bool
fun{} foo(x: int): bool

implement{} foo$y() = false
implement{} foo(x) = let val y = foo$y() in ... end
```

This is actually more flexible than simply supporting default value for a function argument. For instance, foo$y can be re-implemented later:

```
implement{} foo$(y) = true
```

More importantly, foo$y can be implemented in the body of a function calling foo:

```
fun bar(...) = let
  implement foo$y() = ...
in
  ...foo(...)...
end // end of [bar]
```